# how to load images in tableview in ios6 after tableview

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, tableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a table view which is filled with array from json .I also get profile images of the user and that has to be loaded next to the msgs filled by the array .

I have 2 questions here:

1> Do I need to fill the tableview first on the main thread then then fill images in the background which is filled off the main thread or is there any other solution to the above procedure ?

2> How do I load it exactly where the msg is, if the loading of the images takes time and somebody already deletes the msg from the tableview .Will tableview know that the object in that particular cell has been deleted and hence that images which is loading in the background is omitted and proceeds .Or do I need to hold the entire thread on the main thread till the msgs and images are both loaded ?

Please suggest me which is the best solution or solution which you have already implemented .Please consider this question  as an enquiry from all the enthusiasts and beginners in tableview ios6 architecture.

Please share Any link/data related to the above question ios6 storyboard architecture.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1> Do I need to fill the tableview first on the main thread then then fill images in the background which is filled off the main thread
>   or is there any other solution to the above procedure ?

All UI changes must be done on the main thread.  But the downloading of the images (and any processing, like if you want to round the corners) should be done on a background thread.

> 2> How do I load it exactly where the msg is, if the loading of the
>   images takes time and somebody already deletes the msg from the
>   tableview .Will tableview know that the object in that particular cell
>   has been deleted and hence that images which is loading in the
>   background is omitted and proceeds .Or do I need to hold the entire
>   thread on the main thread till the msgs and images are both loaded ?

The table view reflects whatever is in your data source.  It doesn't keep track of anything for you except table cells.  If a user deletes a message and the image hasn't downloaded yet, you should cancel the download of that image.

For image download, you might want to check out the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library which will do lots of this for you.  It enables a "setImageWithURL" method, which you can use like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: (Note that the code sample is from the SDWebImage README; I didn't write it.)

Comment: Thank You Sir for your time and in depth exaplanation.What about grand central dispatch is that necessary in the above case .Currently I have a table view population data via json and now I have links for the images in a array .How do I proceed from here ?? I am new to tableview SO any help would be great.

Comment: There is no block code or dispatch queue in the above code .Is ios6 managing the loading time and display??

Comment: SDWebImage has background thread code for downloading the images.  It's inside the `setImageWithURL` method.  You can see the code here: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/SDWebImage

Comment: You would basically take the images from your away, and put them into where you see `http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg` above.

Comment: Thank you sir but I need to add the SDWebImage library to the project and implement the above code?

Comment: And one more thing does ios6 handle the above requirement instead of library? Just curious ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26745/discussion-between-aaron-brager-and-james-patrick)

Comment: Hi Aaron I implemeted this code in my project with itunes json feed of 50 image arts .There were 2 images that did not load can you please tell me why and how I can fix  ?as I gues the image is in cache memory since its not loading again when I get back to a activity .Thanks again.

Comment: After I closed app completely and restarted the app it worked fine but is there any fix if few images in the list did not load/display.